# JavaScript code not working properly on Android

Tags: android, qml

I'm writing a game of checkers with QML, and I have this component which encompasses the player piece and it's mouse area.

When the mouse is pressed, and the user moves the mouse, the cell underneath is highlighted yellow. This and snapping works on Ubuntu, but when I test it on Android, only dragging pieces seems to work.

This is it working on Ubuntu[image: Animated GIF showing snapping and highlighting when a player piece is moved over a cell]

Here's the code for the player piece:

```
Component {
        id: playerPiece
        Image {
            id: image
            property int cx: 0
            property int cy: 0
            x: board.x + (cx * window.cellSize)
            y: board.y + (cy * window.cellSize)
            property int pieceIndex: -1
            property int pieceType: 0
            MouseArea {
                id: ma
                anchors.fill: parent
                enabled: GameState.playerTurnId == 1 && (pieceType & 1) == 1
                drag.target: parent
                drag.axis: Drag.XAxis | Drag.YAxis
                property int targetCellX: -1
                property int targetCellY: -1
                onReleased: {
//                    console.log("released")
                    if (GameState.lastHighlightedIndex != -1
                            && GameState.lastHighlightedY != -1) {
                        board.children[GameState.lastHighlightedY].children[GameState.lastHighlightedX].children[0].visible = false
                        if (targetCellX != -1 && targetCellY != -1) {
                            console.log(targetCellX)
                            var piece = GameState.playerPieceQMLItems[image.pieceIndex]
                            console.log(`cx ${targetCellX} cy ${targetCellY}`)
                            piece.cx = targetCellX
                            piece.cy = targetCellY
                            //hack to recalculate positions
                            board.x++
                            board.x--
                            board.y++
                            board.y--
                            targetCellX = -1
                            targetCellY = -1
                        }
                    }
                }

                onPositionChanged: {
                    if (drag.active) {
//                        console.log("dragging")
                        var mousePos = NativeFunctions.globalMousePos()
                        targetCellX = Math.floor(
                                    (mousePos.x - window.x - board.x) / window.cellSize)
                        targetCellY = Math.floor(
                                    (mousePos.y - window.y - board.y) / window.cellSize)
                        if ((targetCellX > -1 && targetCellX < 8) && (targetCellY > -1
                                                          && targetCellY < 8)) {
                            GameState.tileState[targetCellX + (targetCellY * 8)] = 3
                            //update the board row column child item
                            var item = board.children[targetCellY].children[targetCellX]
                            if (item instanceof Rectangle) {
                                //remove the highlight from the last highlighted cell
                                if (GameState.lastHighlightedIndex != -1
                                        && GameState.lastHighlightedY != -1) {
                                    board.children[GameState.lastHighlightedY].children[GameState.lastHighlightedX].children[0].visible = false
                                }
                                item.children[0].visible = true
                                //console.log(`selected ${GameState.playerPieceQMLItems[image.pieceIndex]}, pieceIndex ${image.pieceIndex}`)
                                //console.log(`${item.children[1].id}`)
                                GameState.lastHighlightedX = targetCellX
                                GameState.lastHighlightedY = targetCellY
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sourceClipRect: {
                if (GameState.cf(pieceType, GameState.TS_P1)) {
                    //king flag set
                    if (GameState.cf(pieceType, GameState.TS_PK)) {
                        return Qt.rect(0, 326, 338, 338)
                    } else {
                        return Qt.rect(0, 0, 338, 338)
                    }
                } else if (GameState.cf(pieceType, GameState.TS_P2)) {
                    //king flag set
                    if (GameState.cf(pieceType, GameState.TS_PK)) {
                        return Qt.rect(0, 326, 338, 338)
                    } else {
                        return Qt.rect(534, 0, 338, 338)
                    }
                }
            }
            source: "qrc:/pieces.png"
        }
    }
```

Which is a part of https://github.com/ben-cottrell-nz/checkers/blob/master/main.qml.

Why is the highlighting and snapping functionality not working when I test my application on Android?

Comment: I guess that `positionChanged` designed for mouse, see the docs: _This signal is emitted when the mouse position changes_. On Android is not really mouse so I guess you have to change the logic a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my method exposed from C++, `NativeMethods::globalMousePos` was the issue: on Android it was returning -2147483648 for x and y, this was being returned from `QCursor::pos`.

I changed mousePos in my QML code to use the builtin function mapToGlobal:
`var mousePos = mapToGlobal(mouse.x, mouse.y)`

Highlighting and snapping to Rectangles works on Android now.

Comment: I would also check the [MultiPointTouchArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html) item to track a point.